# Bug - How can SELECT GROUP_CONCAT return more than 1 row in subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have a question and I can't seem to have found an answer yet ( tough I have solved the real problem ).

I have a rather big query that worked fine for .. 3-4 months, then after some changes were made by adding items and working within the application a subquery with group_concat returned more than 1 row and I touth the point of group_concat is to concat all items in 1 line ?!

The simplified query is like this :

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,
             (other_selects),
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(' ',IF(user_nume IS NOT NULL, (
                    SELECT CONCAT(user_nume,' ',user_prenume)
                    FROM table
                    WHERE u2.user_id = cal_id_user
                    AND i1.cai_id = cal_id_imobil
                    ), (
                        SELECT user_company
                        FROM table
                        WHERE u2.user_id = cal_id_user
                        AND i1.cai_id = cal_id_imobil
                        ) ))
    FROM table2 u2) as locatari,
    ( other selects )   
    .........................
    FROM table3 i1
    ...... JOINS ............
GROUP BY cai_id
ORDER BY cai_id DESC)t" ;)
```

This subqery is returning to me more than 1 rows and I don't understand how.

I have to mention I removed table name and there is no problem on JOINS or other sintax errors.

The solution for this problem was to add a

```
GROUP BY cal_id_user
```

in both SELECTS inside the IF condition.

Can someone please explain to me how this problem is possible ? I have found no exact answers for this kind of problem unfortunately.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that MySQL allows you to use aggregate functions without a GROUP BY clause which is insane. Without the GROUP BY your query can work in MySQL but this doesn't meen it is correct. (Try this in MSSQL you will see.)

Comment: Yes, but if I make a SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table I always get back 1 row with the concatenated values from that column, so it should never return more than 1 row with or without GROUP BY. If I want just the different values I use DISTINCT.

Comment: instead use MAX(id) in your subquery you dont have to make other changes this will select the last row

Comment: I don't understand why I would need the last row.